# When did the Strogg start assimilating prisoners?

Tags: video-games, quake

We know that the [Strogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strogg#Strogg) in [Quake IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quake_4) recruit their solders by "stroggifying" (i.e. assimilating) their captured human enemies. However, I don't recall them doing so in [Quake II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quake_II).

Was that plot element introduced in the sequel (Quake IV) or were they supposed to have been doing this already in Quake II? If this was *new* behaviour, how was it motivated?

Comment: Quake 2 features whole sections of the meat factories that go into the production of Strogg warriors. I remember vividly scenes of exploded corpses being electrocuted.

Comment: Yeah, the game definitely features it - there are holding cells at some points, and you even, at times, have the option of turning off the machines to save some soldiers.

Comment: [meta discussion about tagging](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2599/2565) (@Iszi)

Comment: The Quake 2 manual makes it quite explicit - "*Unlike humans, the Strogg aren’t just one race. They represent a combination of captured and processed races; a bloody marriage between bone and metal, flesh and machine.*" ("Enemy Profiles" section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a level in Quake 2 called "Detention Center" where you can see a lot of soldiers being processed / killed / assimilated into strogg soldiers as I remember. There is no information about when it started however. Even the Quake wikia page does not have information about this I think that this will remain a secret.